# Subgroups of the integers.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ideals, integers

Theorem: The subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}$ are $n \mathbb{Z}$ for $n=0,1,2....$.

My Proof:
Let $H$ be an arbitrary subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$. Let $x \in H$. If $x<0$ then since $H$ is closed under taking additive inverses, it follows that we can find a positive element in $H$, hence the subset of $H$ with positive integers is non-empty. Let $X$ be the smallest positive integer in $H$. Now, it suffices to show that $H \subset \langle X\rangle$. So let $h \in H$, by the division algorithm, $h=Xq+r$ where $0\leq r< X$. This shows that $h-Xq=r$. Since $h-Xq=h+(-Xq)=r$, it follows that $-Xq,h$ are members of $H$, and since $H$ is closed, $r$ is in $H$. However, since $r<X$ it follows that $r=0$ hence $h=Xq$ and so every element $H$ is a multiple of $X$ and so $H=\langle X\rangle$ is the set of integers that are multiples of $X$.
The case for $x>0$ follows similarly and the case for $x=0$ is trivial..

Is the proof correct? How do I improve it?

Comment: This is fine - just check that your proof that  a subgroup of a cyclic group is cyclic does not use this fact.

Comment: To be rigorous, in your lemma, $n$ is supposed to be non-negative, but $x$ is not necessarily non-negative.

Comment: I'm afraid the theorem about subgroups of cyclic groups you use requires having proved $\mathbf Z$ has this property.

Comment: **Hint:** choose the smallest positive member of the given subgroup.

Comment: I think when you write 'the generator of $X$' you mean: 'the subgroup generated by $X$' (which is a subgroup of which $X$ is the generator). Otherwise the proof seems fine.